# Sync SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2014 Express database in my VB based website site Issue NO such interface supported .net 4.0

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have setup my site on IIS 10 and Window10 (x64) and referenced SQL Server 2014 Express RMO libraries in my website but I'm getting an error:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Com Error Exception: 'No such interface  supported'

when I call the

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.MergeSynchronizationAgent.Synchronize()
```

method. I have followed same code as defined in example

```
// Define the server, publication, and database names.
string subscriberName = subscriberInstance;
string publisherName = publisherInstance;
string distributorName = distributorInstance;
string publicationName = "AdvWorksSalesOrdersMerge";
string subscriptionDbName = "AdventureWorks2012Replica";
string publicationDbName = "AdventureWorks2012";
string hostname = @"adventure-works\garrett1";
string webSyncUrl = "https://" + publisherInstance + SalesOrders/replisapi.dll";


// Create a connection to the Subscriber.
ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(subscriberName);

MergePullSubscription subscription;
MergeSynchronizationAgent agent;

try
{
    // Connect to the Subscriber.
    conn.Connect();

// Define the pull subscription.
subscription = new MergePullSubscription();
subscription.ConnectionContext = conn;
subscription.DatabaseName = subscriptionDbName;
subscription.PublisherName = publisherName;
subscription.PublicationDBName = publicationDbName;
subscription.PublicationName = publicationName;

// If the pull subscription exists, then start the synchronization.
if (subscription.LoadProperties())
{
    // Get the agent for the subscription.
    agent = subscription.SynchronizationAgent;

    // Check that we have enough metadata to start the agent.
    if (agent.PublisherSecurityMode == null)
    {
        // Set the required properties that could not be returned
        // from the MSsubscription_properties table. 
        agent.PublisherSecurityMode = SecurityMode.Integrated;
        agent.DistributorSecurityMode = SecurityMode.Integrated;
                 agent.Distributor = publisherName;
                 agent.HostName = hostname;

        // Set optional Web synchronization properties.
        agent.UseWebSynchronization = true;
        agent.InternetUrl = webSyncUrl;
        agent.InternetSecurityMode = SecurityMode.Standard;
        agent.InternetLogin = winLogin;
        agent.InternetPassword = winPassword;
    }
    // Enable agent output to the console.
    agent.OutputVerboseLevel = 1;
    agent.Output = "";

    // Synchronously start the Merge Agent for the subscription.
    agent.Synchronize();
}


else
    {
        // Do something here if the pull subscription does not exist.
        throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(
            "A subscription to '{0}' does not exist on {1}",
            publicationName, subscriberName));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Implement appropriate error handling here.
    throw new ApplicationException("The subscription could not be " +
        "synchronized. Verify that the subscription has " +
        "been defined correctly.", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in the following website?  Did you add library from Visual Studio menu Project : Add Reference?  You can verify from Solution Explorer under Reference.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/concepts/replication-management-objects-concepts?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I followed same steps defined in that article I think it something with SQL server version support for publisher, distributor and subscriber. Since I have tested it with SQL server 2016 standard and SQL express 2014 version . its working fine . but it's giving **No Such Interface supported** Issue with SQL server 2014 standard and SQL express 2014.

Comment: There is a 2014 version of the msdn webpage : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/concepts/replication-management-objects-concepts?view=sql-server-2014.  So I do not think it is version.  Are you using Standard or Express?  Express doesn't have all features.  You may be missing a library.  Are you using Net 4.0 in working case or a later version?  You may need to publish you app and install on IIS which will take missing dll (which contains the libraries) and update the IIS with missing libraries.

Comment: I have sql server 2014 standard with version 12.0.5589 and same one for sql express 2014 v 12.0.5589 with x64 bit . I followed all steps as described in article. when I call it using RMO from web application on client or on windows console app both gives me "No Such Interface supported" error on call agent.synchronize() method.

Comment: I not an expert in SQL Licensing.  What I think is happening is your Standard doesn't have the license install correctly so it is defaulting to express options.  See : https://www.directionsonmicrosoft.com/sites/default/files/PDFs/Licensing_Changes_for_SQL_Server_2014.pdf

Comment: I figured out I got **No Such Interface Supported error** when I use 

 `// Set optional Web synchronization properties.  
                    agent.UseWebSynchronization = true;
                    agent.InternetUrl = webSyncUrl;
                    agent.InternetSecurityMode = SecurityMode.Standard;
                    agent.InternetLogin = winLogin;
                    agent.InternetPassword = winPassword;`
Any idea ?

Comment: Can you connect to database using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?  I'm not sure if the error is the credentials to the database, or your connection string.   So if you can connect using SSMS then it is not the credentials and you need to check the connection string.

Comment: Thanks for yours suggestions . I was able to resolve it. it was related to credentials problem on client and server end users. When I set that correctly it starts running and did the migration. :)